# Workflow Task - Access Denied to User

Tags: workflow, access

Using SharePoint Designer I created an OOTB approval workflow using `Start Approval Process` action.

When the user to whom the task has been assigned tries to approve/reject they get access denied. They have Contribute access to the task list and to the document library. What am I missing?

Comment: is it like all users should approve or only one need to approve?

Comment: also did you try giving "Approve" permission?